# Problem while printing characters Difference between System.out.println('A') and System.out.println(+'A')

Tags: java, data, strings, ascii

Why is it that :

```
 System.out.println(+'A')   //gives output as 65

  System.out.println('A')   //gives output as A
```

Also

```
 System.out.println(8+4+'A'+"PRIME"+4+4+'A');
```

gives output as **77PRIME44A**

Why is it that 8+4 before the String "Prime" are **being added**, while 4+4 after "Prime" are being **printed as it is** ?

I also have a doubt why 8+4+'A' results in **65(ascii of A)**+12=77
whereas 4+4+'A' *doesn't include A's ascii* getting added up ?

Is there any ***specific rule or convention*** regarding the above ?

Comment: Short answer: type coercion (aka implicit type conversion) + left-associative operator `+`

Comment: Welcome to programmers.SE. We only support [on-topic](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) questions.  This may be answered on [stackoverflow.com](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). There are [many sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites) with [different rules](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/8066/i-have-a-question-but-it-may-not-fit-best-on-programmers-where-else-can-i-ask/8067#8067). Feel free to move this question to an appropriate site. Please [don't cross post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info) by failing to delete it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> System.out.println(+'A')   //gives output as 65

In the expression `+'A'` the unary plus operator ([indicating a positive integer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html)) gets applied to `'A'` and the expression only makes sense if the char [is converted](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html) to an `int`. The character `'A'` has the int value of 65 ([see the ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/)), which is why the whole expression evaluates to 65, which then gets printed.

> System.out.println(8+4+'A'+"PRIME"+4+4+'A');
>
> gives output as 77PRIME44A
>
> Why is it that 8+4 before the String "Prime" are being added, while 4+4 after "Prime" are being printed as it is ?

Because the [associativity of `+`](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/) (both for integer addition and for string concatenation) is left-to-right. So first you do `8+4`, which is integer addition, then `12+'A'` (which requires `'A'` to be interpreted as its integer value 65), and then you have `+"PRIME"`. But this only makes sense as string concatenation, which is why it results in `"77PRIME"`; afterwards every call to `+` is a string concatenation; the integers get converted to their string equivalents (4 -> "4") and the result of a string + char operation shouldn't surprise you.

So it's

```
8+4+'A'+"PRIME"+4+4+'A' 
--> ((((((8+4)+'A')+"PRIME")+4)+4)+'A')    // placed explicit parenthesis
--> (((((12+'A')+"PRIME")+4)+4)+'A')       // int addition 8+4
--> ((((77+"PRIME")+4)+4)+'A')             // int addition, 'A' cast to int 65
--> ((("77PRIME")+4)+4)+'A')               // string concat, 77 converted to "77"
--> (("77PRIME4"+4)+'A')                   // string concat, 4 --> "4"
--> ("77PRIME44"+'A')                      // ditto
--> "77PRIME44A"                           // string + char concat
```

Comment: It's not an expansion to `0 + 'A'`, but rather just an unary plus.

Comment: @scriptin Thanks! You're right. I've corrected my answer.

Comment: Downvoter(s): I welcome corrections. If I made a mistake as to exactly which type coercion or operator precedence rule applies, please edit it instead of downvoting. Thanks.